# Getting Cipher Message Authentication Failed

Tags: go, aes

I am creating a middleware function to decrypt the request body of an api call but cannot seem to get it working. The body is encrypted and then base64 encoded before the request is made. Any help would be appreciated.

My curent function code:

```
            ciphertext, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err.Error())
            }
            ciphertext = decodeBase64(string(ciphertext))

            block, err := aes.NewCipher(keyString)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err.Error())
            }

            aesgcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(block)
            if err != nil {
               panic(err.Error())
            }  

            nonce := make([]byte, aesgcm.NonceSize())
            clearStuff := make([]byte, len(ciphertext))
            plaintext, err := aesgcm.Open(clearStuff, nonce, ciphertext, nil)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err.Error())
            }
            fmt.Println(string(plaintext))
```

The key is:

```
var keyString = []byte("ECB518652A170880555136EA1F9752D6")
```

The error im getting is:

```
cipher: message authentication failed []
```

I'm pretty sure that the issue is stemming from `ciphertext` but I haven't been able to find a solution to the problem. I found a working solution [here](https://go.dev/play/p/eExssNO1LP0), but its using the seal to decrypt and that won't be possible in my case. So how can I get this done?

Comment: The code actually works, s. https://go.dev/play/p/FzkiKIsG8gK. So the problem will rather be a difference to the encryption logic or inconsistent data. You should post some test data, i.e. besides the test key, the nonce, the plaintext and the corresponding ciphertext. If possible you should also post the encryption code (e.g. to check encodings, nonce and tag handling etc.).

Comment: _...but its using the seal to decrypt..._ No, the linked code uses `Seal()` for *encryption* (and decrypts with `Open()`).

Comment: @Topaco yes I meant it would use the output of `Seal()` to help decrypt the data. But okay I will try it again with better data, thank you.

Comment: @Tapaco how did you encrypt the value in the link you posted? I've tried to reproduce it but am running into the same problem.

Comment: You are trying to implement a decryption, but you do not post the information needed for this task, namely the code for the encryption and test data. So only guesses can be made. Regarding the ciphertext in the link: Perform an encryption with AES/GCM using your key and a zero nonce (the latter is a fatal bug for GCM btw) and concatenate ciphertext and tag (some libraries do this implicitly).